# Django: Returning a queryset ordered according to a list of primary keys

Tags: django-models

I have a list L of primary keys and I would like to return an ordered queryset where the ordering  of the objects corresponds to primary key order in L.

Unfortunately

```
Model.objects.filter(id__in = L)
```

does not maintain the ordering.

Is there any other command which maintains the order?

Answer (score 0):

Apply the same ordering as before or sort it afterwards with Python.